# Huawei Map suddenly unable to load and crash

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

The map was working right before suddenly started to crash on activity open.

The code was same as working and no changes made. what coul be the problem?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    mapView = findViewById(R.id.map);
    checkPermission();

    if (permission) {
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
@Override protected void onStart() { super.onStart(); mMapView.onStart(); }

@Override protected void onResume() { super.onResume(); mMapView.onResume(); }

@Override protected void onPause() { super.onPause(); mMapView.onPause(); }

@Override protected void onStop() { super.onStop(); mMapView.onStop(); }

@Override protected void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy(); mMapView.onDestroy(); }

@Override public void onLowMemory() { super.onLowMemory(); mMapView.onLowMemory(); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code did not change, it could be that the permission of app changed.

perhaps it was reinstalled and uninstalled?

looking at the code, the oncreate is called after permission check.

we need to either ask for permission again, or have the app proceed without map. one of two choices.

This should prevent NullPointerException.

also for permission request, we need to handle SecurityException to avoid crashing.